# Posting result of axios

Tags: javascript, express, axios

Currently have this piece of code it gets me the data i need but idk how to post/showcase the data on the website page and not the console file? i tried post and everything i could think of

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () =>console.log('success'));
app.use(express.static('public'));


var axios = require('axios');
const { response } = require('express');

var config = {
 // method -> 'get', 'post', 'delete', 'put'
  method: 'get',
  // API endpoint -> 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations'; 
  // API endpoint with query parameters -> 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations?sort=name'
  url: 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations',
  // sindle header -> header: { 'key': 'value'}
  // multiple header -> header: { 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
  headers: { }
};

// If API response is success then would be executed, else catch block would be executed.
axios(config).then((response) => {
    // data = response.data
    // To parse data to json -> JSON.parse(response.data)
    // To parse data to string -> JSON.stringify(response.data)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
  return response.data;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to add an express API route that returns this data? So that you can load `/my-api-path` on your website and get the JSON back? This pattern is well documented online.

Comment: Hi yes i tried that and it returned an error every time I'm not sure at this point

Comment: Your code doesn't have any express routes in it. This question will likely be closed because it doesn't have enough debugging details. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and edit this question, or open a new one if this question is closed. If "it" "returned an error" we can't help you without knowing what either of those things mean.

Comment: i removed it as it kept causing me 
a. errors and or b just nothing happening on screen
I'm new to coding and i don't mind if the question is shut down i thought i could get help somewhere if it isn't here then idk but thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it listens to `/my-api-path` and returns the result.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
var axios = require('axios');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/my-api-path', (req, res) => {
  var config = {
 // method -> 'get', 'post', 'delete', 'put'
  method: 'get',
  // API endpoint -> 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations'; 
  // API endpoint with query parameters -> 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations?sort=name'
  url: 'https://api.eventyay.com/v1/event-locations',
  // sindle header -> header: { 'key': 'value'}
  // multiple header -> header: { 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
  headers: { }
};

// If API response is success then would be executed, else catch block would be executed.
axios(config).then((response) => {
    // data = response.data
    // To parse data to json -> JSON.parse(response.data)
    // To parse data to string -> JSON.stringify(response.data)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
  res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
res.send("Error "+error.toString());
});
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```